Is there a rule-of-thumb for the coefficient of friction between different kinds of surfaces?
Suppose we have a surface $a$ and we know what its coefficient of friction is when sliding against an identical surface. Let's call that $\mu_{aa}$. Then suppose we have a different kind of surface $b$ with a coefficient of friction $\mu_{bb}$. Based on this information, could we guesstimate the coefficient of friction $\mu_{ab}$ of these two different surfaces when sliding against each other. I.e. is there some kind of function $f$ such that $\mu_{ab}\approx f(\mu_{aa}, \mu_{bb})$. I do realize that $\mu_{aa}$ and $\mu_{bb}$ need not uniquely determine the result in general. I'm just wondering if there's some function that would be a decent approximation in a majority of cases. Would e.g. an average, a minimum, or a maximum be a decent approximation?
Alternatively, is there some kind table of coefficients of friction between a large number of different kind of surfaces (including between identical surfaces) freely available online? I could try to make some kind of function fit myself if I could find that kind of data somewhere.
EDIT:
So Bob D provided a link to a table with friction coefficients in a comment under his answer. It had too many gaps in the sliding friction coefficient column but the static friction coefficient column was better, though the data was still a bit sparse. I tried a simple least-squares fit where the function would be a linear combination of min and max of the two self-friction coefficients such that I force $f(x,x)=x$. Basically, this means a form of:
$$f(x,y)=q\min(x,y)+(1-q)\max(x,y)$$
I only got 7 data points from the table so having more than one parameter is probably not a good idea without more data. The result I got was roughly $q=0.85$, so basically the function I got was $f(x,y)=0.85\min(x,y)+0.15\max(x,y)$. So it seems that at least in this data set the friction coefficient generally seems to be closer to the lower one of the two self-friction coefficients (and even below). The $R^2$ of this fit was roughly $0.85$ (not the same as the coefficient $q$ but close). This seems fairly good but with just 7 data points that doesn't necessarily mean much and I don't know how well this fit would work outside this data set.

Conversely, can you suggest how that might work?
There are simple equations for calculating friction between surfaces but how would your 'rule of thumb' work?
Would it look at 'this sand-paper is red and that is black so (technical details)…' or what, specifically?

@RobbieGoodwin At the end of the first paragraph of my question I wondered whether $f(\mu_{aa}, \mu_{bb})$ being e.g. $\frac{\mu_{aa}+\mu_{bb}}{2}$, $\min(\mu_{aa}, \mu_{bb})$, or $\max(\mu_{aa}, \mu_{bb})$ might work. If I could find some data somewhere, I could maybe myself check if any of these or some other function might land at least somewhat close to the data.

Please either go back and think again, or simply look at Bob D's Answer, below.
If you're interested in friction, what 'rule of thumb' might dictate how hard one car smashes into another from the rear or either side, let alone head on?

@RobbieGoodwin I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here. I'm asking this question out of curiosity. I'm not suggesting any such approximation would be good enough for engineers to use.

Really? Why not think again about that? The whole point of a 'rule of thumb' is that broadly, it is good enough to be used by everyone interested, including all your engineers.
If you've allowed yourself to be misled by proponents of the decimal system, over and against the common-or-garden Imperial system, why did you let your guard down so far?

@RobbieGoodwin An approximation might be good enough in some contexts but inadequate in others. It's not clear to me, how good this kind of approximation could be. I don't see what you're trying to communicate with your mention of the decimal system.

Do you truly believe anyone who uses rules of thumb isn't aware that approximations might be good enough in some contexts but inadequate in others?
That's pretty-much why such aides are called 'rules of thumb.'
Speaking of inadequate in others, 'rule of thumb' as you used it, as a definition or explanation, comes without hyphens.
Only when it's descriptive, as for example of a 'rule-of-thumb result' should there be hyphens.
Feel free to ignore the decimal system except that it quite literally has no place for 'rule of thumb.'

Why not just ask your search engine of choice for 'table of coefficients of friction'?

@RobbieGoodwin I don't remember exactly what I have searched and found. I've thought about this some while ago. In any case, I thought that maybe people here would know better sources than what I could find. At least searching that now I couldn't at least quickly find more extensive tables than the one on Engineering Toolbox that Bob D linked to.

Good for you and why should anyone here trouble to guess what you didn't remember Searching for?
If they did, that wouldn't change the fact that your Question was more than likely a hiding to nothing…

@RobbieGoodwin Obviously no one is obligated to answer my questions but I can still try. At least I did get a little bit of data.

Again, why should anyone trouble to guess what you didn't remember? Broadly, why should anyone here do your work for you?

@RobbieGoodwin They don't have to guess. Bob D's answer works without him presumably having made such guesses. And again, I'm not saying that anyone here should do anything. I'm just asking questions and people might answer if it strikes their fancy.

Whatever else, how would you measure either different, or different  kinds of surfaces?
Are you Asking about wood and metal generally, or oak and copper specifically, or what?

@RobbieGoodwin Well, I'm not about to measure friction coefficients myself. I don't know how precisely such measurements are carried out but I'd imagine it involves pressing surfaces together with a certain force and then dragging them along each other with another force and measuring how much force that takes.

@RobbieGoodwin As to what kinds of surfaces I was talking about, I wasn't really restricting this to only specific types of surfaces. Of course, the more restrictive the set of surfaces the more accurate this kind of approximation could potentially be. I would probably want to exclude anisotropic surfaces like wood because anisotropy would make this a whole lot more complicated.

Good for you. You're maybe half way there. Now, are you Asking about wood and metal generally, or oak and copper specifically, or what?

@RobbieGoodwin Did you read my second comment after your previous comment? I split my response to two comments because of the character limit. In any case, I'm asking generally, not just about one kind of surface like copper (though I probably wouldn't include wood because anisotropic surfaces are an additional complication I want to avoid)

Why not just accept Bob D's Answer and all the Comments thereunder?

@RobbieGoodwin I already accepted Bob D's answer almost 3 weeks ago.

Really? And yet through all that time, you've been quibbling. Oops!

@RobbieGoodwin You can see it from the green check mark on left side of the answer.


I'm just wondering if there's some function that would be a decent
approximation in a majority of cases.

It would be nice, but there isn't. The coefficients of friction are empirically determined, that is, determined by observation or experience rather than theory or pure logic.
To quote from the Hyperphysics web site regarding the difference between static and kinetic friction coefficients :http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html#kin
"When carefully standardized surfaces are used to measure the friction coefficients, the difference between static and kinetic coefficients tends to disappear, indicating that the difference may have to do with irregular surfaces, impurities, or other factors which can be frustratingly non-reproducible".
That being said, I wouldn't want to discourage you from attempting to, as you say, find some "kind of function $f$ such that $\mu_{ab}\approx f(\mu_{aa}, \mu_{bb})$.". To that end, you might find the data in the following link useful:
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html
Hope this helps.

I'm not asking for a theoretical explanation (though obviously that would be even better). Empirical data might happen to fall close to a some kind of neat function or it might not. So far, it's not clear to me whether that's the case or not and I'd like to know. As for the difference between static and kinetic friction, that's a somewhat different issue. I'm mostly thinking about kinetic friction here.

Nevertheless, I’m not aware of the existence of any “neat” function that the empirical data falls close to. That’s my point

Do you, alternatively, know where to find the data so I could try to check myself? By data I mean a list of friction coefficients between pairs of different kinds of surfaces.

@QuantumWiz Yes. Check out this site: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html

It is not just that there isn't a known function that approximates this. It is that such a function cannot exist. Feynman lectures argued why, which is also repeated as in Bob's answer.

@naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure how you can justify the claim that it cannot exist. I didn't even specify how good of an approximation it would have to be. It certainly can exist if the requirements are sufficiently relaxed. The question is whether such approximation can be sufficiently good as to not be completely uninteresting and that's a partially subjective question. I'll play around with the data in Bob D's link when I have the time.

Well, you should read up why we are saying that it cannot exist. It is not thrown around lightly.

@QuantumWiz As far as I’m aware the coefficient of friction has to be determined experimentally. I know of no source that says it can be calculated. There are just too many variables

@naturallyInconsistent Can you give me a link then?

You should have looked it up. https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_12.html#Ch12-S2

@naturallyInconsistent The friction chapter behind that link doesn't really address my question at all. My question was, to what extent could the coefficient of friction between two different kinds of surfaces be approximated using some kind of function of the coefficients of friction that those surfaces have against identical surfaces.

@BobD But that it has to be determined experimentally doesn't really have much bearing on my question since I'm only asking for an approximation. You can always make some kind of approximation. The question is, how good can that kind of approximation be and what form would the best approximation take. It could be that even the best possible approximation would be so bad as to be uninteresting but showing that would require experimental data.

@BobD I looked at the data behind your link. Unfortunately, for sliding friction there were too many gaps. For static friction there was a bit more data, though not much. Basically, the result was that generally the friction coefficient between two different materials was more often closer to the lower of the self friction coefficients of the two materials. I tried a simple fit and the $R^2$ was about 0.85. That doesn't sound too bad but I basically had to make a fit to 7 data points. I did ask for such data as an alternative, so I'm considering if I should accept this as an answer.

It cannot exist because once it is pure enough, you can have contact welding happening, and between different materials, whether it would weld at all or not is also a complicated happenstance.

@naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure why contact welding would be relevant here. Obviously, the metal-on-metal friction coefficients would usually be measured with the kind of surfaces that we usually have here on earth, i.e. ones with an oxide layer on them. I wasn't requiring that the material would have to be pure and it can also be something other than metal also. For that matter, in my question I asked about different kinds of surfaces, not different kinds of materials.

Those are surfaces of materials. Even with oxide layers, there can be nonlinearities that disrupt the friction coefficient determination.

@BobD OK, I looked at that data on Engineering Toolbox and added a discussion of it to my question. I think I can accept your answer if you add that link to your answer. The data was a bit sparse but I think I won't be getting more extensive data as an answer to my question.

@QuantumWiz I've added the link to my answer. With regard to the analysis you done so far, may I offer a suggestion. In addition to trying to find an overall function as you have done so far, you might consider grouping the data with respect to categories of materials and looking for separate functions within each category. In my work experience in analyzing electrical, mechanical, and combustibility of materials, you might want to separate the metals from non metals.

In the non metals, subdivide into polymers that are thermoplastics, thermosets, elastomers, etc. Finally, natural organics (woods). You might find higher correlations within the groupings than for materials overall. Good luck!

@BobD Using additional information like material type might indeed allow for a more precise approximation. But to try something like that I would need more data than what Engineering Toolbox had.

@QuantumWiz I absolutely agree. Not only more data but also more information on the data given. What are the sources? What tests were used? Are the tests used to determine the coefficients standardized (like ASTM D 1894)? So many questions.
